# Are there third party GUIs to manage OTP applications?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Is there anything like the weblogic console, but for administrating an OTP application (written in Erlang)?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "administrating" an OTP application? Do you mean some sort of "Operation and Maintainance" web application?

Comment: Yes, something where I can monitor everything, and start, stop and deploy services

Comment: SNMP is implemented by the VM, so you can do some monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know.

You could use one of the available web frameworks (Erlang Web, Nitrogen, etc) to build one on your own.

Alternatives are to use a web front-end written in any of the "traditional" languages and to make it interact with an Erlang back-end. Possibilities are:

- [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/)
- [Apache Erlang extension for php](http://www.math-hat.com/~zukerman/projects/php-erlang/)
- [erl_interface](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erl_interface/index.html)

I would honestly prefer the first approach (Erlang powered web framework).

Comment: When you say none are available, do you mean there is no commerical offering either?

Comment: As far as I know, there are commercial companies developing and/or providing consultancy for O&M applications, but there's not a general "package" so far, that you can download somewhere.